# Jenkins fails on "Connection timed out" when running automated tests. Locally they work fine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run some tests (that work fine locally) on jenskins but it never reaches the desired URL and always fails on time out. Can anyone help me? Thank you! Log bellow (I put some sensible information into curly brackets like {endpoint} or {apiUrl}:

`TAM GET /api/latest/{endpoint} user: Connect to {apiUrl}:443 [{apiUrl}/104.18.4.32, [{apiUrl}/104.18.5.32] failed: Connection timed out/n[org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156), org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376), org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393), org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236), org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186), org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89), org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110), org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185), org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83), org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108), org.feg.group.tacore.core.base.api.Request.executeGenericRequest(Request.java:241), org.feg.group.tacore.core.base.api.Request.executeGet(Request.java:103), org.feg.group.tacore.core.base.api.Request.execute(Request.java:68), org.feg.group.tacore.core.base.api.Client.execute(Client.java:90), org.feg.group.tacore.core.base.api.ApiDriver.executeRequest(ApiDriver.java:118), … java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77), java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568), org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139), org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:677), org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221), org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50), org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:969), org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194), org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148), org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128), java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511), org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:829), org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602), org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:437), org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:431), org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:391), org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330), org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52), org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95), org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256), org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176), org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099), org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067), org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:308), org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:71), org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:113), org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385), org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162), org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507), org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)]`

- The api request works in IDE and in my browser. The issue shouldn't be related to VPN access or so.
- The same test works fine on different enviroments.

Comment: Can you confirm that your Jenkins server can reach the "desired URL"? Show proof.

Comment: It cannot, that's the problem.

Comment: Sounds like whomever is managing the infrastructure misconfiguration something somewhere. If that is you, you might be able to get help over at [sf].

Comment: Instead of repeating "locally works fine" run it (manually) on the jenkins node. Looks like in this case you don't even have to run the entire test. Just login on the jenkins node which runs this and try to reach the API from there...